# How to access data from unique .txt file at runtime using .exe created with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, executable

I am working on a python project that generates unique diplomas/certificates as pdfs based on a list of names. The program reads a list of names into a python list and then "pastes" each of these names onto a new blank diploma. I am using the PyPDF4 and ReportLab modules to do this. I am using PyCharm and the program works perfectly when I run it in the IDE.

The issue is that I want to give this to a friend who knows nothing about programming. I want to give him a folder that contains an executable and generates the output pdfs in the same folder. All he should have to do is add 2 files to the directory (a list of names and a diploma template) and double click the executable. I tried to use pyinstaller for this, but ran into an issue accessing the data files.

There are 2 data files that the program uses: **names.txt** (list of names) and **template.pdf** (the blank diploma). I navigated into my project directory and ran `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`. After running the .exe, this is the error I got: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'names.txt'`

I tried using the `--add-data` option for pyinstaller, but I'm not sure that was the right idea. I need the executable to simply look inside it's own working directory at runtime and use the files called names.txt and template.pdf that the user will add to the directory.

Does that make sense and is it even possible? Any help would be appreciated.

## =======
UPDATE=======

Here is an image of the project directory after running `pyinstaller --onefile --add-data 'names.txt:.' --add-data 'template.pdf:.' main.py`:

[image: Main project directory and 'dist' subdirectory]

And here is the code from the main.spec file:

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/josiahbrown/Desktop/diploma'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('names.txt', '.'), ('template.pdf', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Even if I add names.txt to the dist folder, when I run main.exe I get the same error.

Comment: How are you trying to access the the text in `.py` file?
Is the text file in the same folder as of the `.py` file?

Comment: I am accessing the text using: "with open("names.txt", "r") as f:...
And yes, the data files are both in the same folder as the main .py file

Answer (score 0):

Please show your `main.conf` which was created by pyinstaller.

There should be a section `datas=[('PATH_TO_FILE\\names.txt', '.'),('PATH_TO_FILE\\template.pdf', '.')]` where PATH_TO_FILE is the absolute path

Comment: datas=[...] is currently empty. I know that I can add the paths to the files and it will work on my own computer, but wouldn't the absolute paths to the data files change if I ran it on a different computer?

Comment: This is only used for _compiling_  In the tuple `('PATH_TO_FILE\\template.pdf', '.')` the second entry is the target, in this case `'.'` means the program base path. Take a look at [Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/)

Comment: Details you'll find at [https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html]

Comment: Ok that makes more sense but I am still getting the same error. Here is the command that I ran from inside the project folder: 

pyinstaller --onefile --add-data 'names.txt:.' --add-data 'template.pdf:.' main.py

After running this, the names.txt file was still not found when I ran the executable located inside .../project/dist. I also added the names file into the dist folder and it was still not able to find it

Comment: I have added an update to my question above that might give a little more info

Comment: Hm, your main.conf seems not to be complete. Delete it and start pyinstaller again, it will create a new one. And add the full path to data section e.g. at names.txt.

Comment: The main.spec image was only showing the first few lines. I have updated the question now to include the entire file. As to your second point, if I specify a full path, I get the following error: Unable to find "/Users/josiahbrown/Desktop/diploma/${HOME}/Desktop/diploma/names.txt" when adding binary and data files. It looks like the "pathex" variable in the main.spec file contains the full path to the project directory and is appended when adding data

Comment: `"${HOME}"` could this be a problem? It seems not to be a valid descriptor to me. Have you tested a real path in all notations? (/ and \\ ) ? Try simple paths for testing.